# Spring CSRF fetch (POST) fails (Client: react-native / Javascript)

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, react-native, fetch

I'd read some suggestions on here. Unfortunately the suggestions couldn't solve my problem. GETting data causes no problem, however POSTing data doesn't works.
Trying to fetch-post data returns 403 - Forbidden. **When disabling CSRF in configure-method in Spring Boot...**

```
http.csrf().disable();
```

**...everything works fine. But that's not the solution I'm looking for.**

```
    fetch('http://IP:PORT/path', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: new Headers({
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }),
        body: JSON.stringify(myBody),
        credentials: 'same-origin'
    }).then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => console.log(response))

    .catch(error=>
        console.log(error)
    );
```

Neither credentials: 'same-origin' nor 'include' was helpful, to solve the problem. I hope to find some help here, otherwise I've to disable csrf :/

Comment: Hi same here. Have you figure out how to solve it?

Comment: I guess it might be a little bit late but I'll post an answer for the future ones that are facing the same problem.